# Are there animated cursors for the mac?

Tags: macos, mac, cursor

My wife and I recently upgraded to a mac (loving it) and we're trying to find some animated cursors.

Do you know of any site out there that has them?  Free would be preferred but if they cost a few bucks I don't mind.

G-Man

Comment: " but if they cost a few bucks I don't mind" - Switch to Mac, pay an arm and a leg for everything. hehe.

Comment: Never understood the appeal of these.

Comment: @Benjamin Neither did I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit anti on the Mac to use animated cursors, and even themes and colors are tightly controlled in OS X. Having said that, the only application I know of that works on 10.6 is [PinPoint](http://www.macchampion.com/MacChampion/Welcome.html) by MacChampion, which may or may not be what you expect of animated cursors. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here: https://github.com/alexzielenski/Mousecape

(And some more text because the 11 I typed in above is not enough to post)